# How to type the cookies of Express in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to get the constant `jwt` to be equal to a string, however, for some reason it's being enforced to become `any`.

How can I type the cookies of Express correctly using TypeScript?

```
import Administrator from '@/models/Administrator'
import { NextFunction, Request } from 'express'

type DemoRoute = (req: ProtectedRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void

export const demoRoute: DemoRoute = (req, res, next) => {
  const loggedInUser = req.$USER // ? Administrator
  const jwt = req.cookies.jwt // any
}

type ProtectedRequest = Request & {
  $USER: Administrator
  cookies: {
    jwt: string
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not "enforced" - `req.cookies` is `any`, so any property of `req.cookies` is also `any`. `any & { jwt: string }` is... `any`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I don't know. I also tried to do module augmentation, it also behaved the same way

Comment: Module **augmentation** isn't going to _narrow_ existing types. Again `any & { jwt: string }` [is `any`](https://tsplay.dev/w1L5yW), and any property of `any` is `any`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any

Comment: What is going on here any is any 

Comment: @jonrsharpe, what's the solution then?